# Javascript Remove all periods preceded by a character

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a price string i.e: `Rs. 1.2345,99`

I need to remove all letters and all periods preceded by a letter.

So a string that was `Rs. .1245.3445. s. 34. ffgg.` would result in `.1245.3445  34.`

My expected result is `1.2345,99`

I should add that in the case of `Rs. .954` I also expect a result of `.954`

This is what I have tried:

```
string.replace(/[^0-9+-]|(?!^)[+-]/g, '');
```

But it does ALL of the decimals. Regex is NOT my strong point.

I need this to work with ANY strings not specifically this example string.

Comment: show efforts...

Comment: `myString.split(' ').pop()`. Please be less broad though

Comment: or `str.replace(/Rs\./i,"")`

Comment: what's with all the down votes? A little harsh for someone trying to learn, great community of people here /s

I re-iterate:
I need to remove ALL letters and ALL periods preceded by a letter.

So a string that was `Rs. .1245.3445. s. 34. ffgg.` would result in `.1245.3445 34.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best to break it down into multiple replaces.

First remove letters and periods that follow letters, then you can clean up whitespace:

```js
var x = "Rs. 1.2345,99";
x = x.replace(/[\a-zA-Z]+[\.]*/g,"");
x = x.replace(/\s/g, "");
console.log(x);
```

Note that you only mention letters and periods, if you need other characters removing too then include then in the `[\a-zA-Z]` part.

Comment: `x.replace(/[\a-zA-Z]+[\.]*/g,"")` This matches the entire string

Comment: @djm204: What do you mean by that? What is the problem? Give me an example input that doesn't work correctly

Comment: using regex 101 to test this string `Rs. .100. s.`  and it matches on all chars.  so it actually wipes out the entire string if I do a replace on it.

Comment: @djm204: [it works fine in this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qtypb0c3/)

Comment: Hmm okay then Regex101 is lying to me :P Thanks! I will try it out in my actual code and accept if it works, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

This should do

```
var str = "Rs. 1.2345,99";
str = str.slice(4, str.length);
console.log(str);
```

Comment: This is too specific for my case. Thanks though

Comment: i made it more specific cause i didn't want to extend it... the question that u gave was so simple and was not worthy of being posted on stack overflow... u could have simply googled it - "How to cut out parts from a string in javascript"